# height map on unity material results in wrong texture on border

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just set a material with a texture and a height map, but the height map doesn't work as I expected, on the edge border you see through the texture, and doesn't stretch the pixel on the border, like in the picture, how can I fix this.

In the picture in the blue line is the strange "see through" texture.

[image: border with blue line]

Texture
[image: texture]

heightMap 
[image: heightMap]

Answer (score 0):

Are there polygon edges across the location of the seam? Heightmaps create seams if the edges are not connected. Edges should be shared between the 2 adjacent polygons. 
Try to weld the vertices in a 3D edtor like maya or 3dsmax.

Comment: Hi @hacky, I'm using the unity plane, so there might be and might not be edges hard to tell, I thought the height map would create a virtual height and at a certain view angle the shader would change the viewing pixel by one as if that "height existed" so naturally it should be a border black, or a grey from the texture. No ? and what do you mean by weld the vector.

Comment: hmm, the unity plane has all welded edges/vertices, so that could not be the problem then. Can you tell some more about the project? What shader do you use and does the gap appear to move if you rotate the view around?

Comment: Sure, I'm using standard shader, I added to the main post the height map and texture.